# Doom Emacs: Turn off single line comment autocompletion

Tags: emacs, formatting, comments, indentation, evil-mode

I currently have this Doom Emacs functionality:

```
/*
 *
 * <- automatically inserted after pressing ENTER [good]
 */

//
// <- automatically inserted after pressing ENTER [bad]
```

What could elisp code could I place in my config file such that it DOESNT place a newline after a singleline comment `//` but DOES add a newline after a multiline `/* */` comment?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other now. Thx.